# App not responding and crashing after giving runtime storage permission

Tags: android, android-webview, android-permissions, crash, android-runtime

My app successfully runs when launched and give access to external storage runtime permission  first time but when I launch it second time it does not respond to anything and crashing. Unable to understand..
I was developing a simple navigation drawer web view app.

here is my main activity

```js
import static com.izhandroid.izhandroidapps.R.id.webView;


    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow permission to download and save files", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkPermission()) {

            } else {
                requestPermission(); // Code for permission
            }
        } else {


        }
    }

        private boolean checkPermission() {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void requestPermission() {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please go to app settings and allow permission to download files.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tip: Pull down to refresh",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                    }
                    break;
            }


            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe) ;
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                LoadWeb();

            }
        });

        LoadWeb();

    }
    public void LoadWeb(){

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
        final WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().getJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically();
        wv.getSettings().getDisplayZoomControls();
        wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture();
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);

        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        //refreshLayout(this);

        wv.loadUrl("http://izhandroidwebdemo.blogspot.com");
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Loading, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(){

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,String failingUrl){
                wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
            }

            //@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            // setTitle(view.getTitle());
            }
        });
        wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file-webapp");
                DownloadManager dm =(DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }


    protected void initializeOptions() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

            wv.loadUrl("http://izhandroidwebdemo.blogspot.com");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Loading, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_linkone) {

            wv.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/mohdizhanali");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Loading, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_linktwo) {

            wv.loadUrl("http://www.instagram.com/aninnocentguy");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Loading, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_linkthree) {

            wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Loading, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_linkfour) {
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");


        } else if (id == R.id.mail) {
            //wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
            Intent localIntent1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.SENDTO", Uri.fromParts("mailto", "idappshelp@gmail.com", null));
            localIntent1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "Feedback");
            localIntent1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "Hi Team,");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent1, "Send email..."));

        } else if (id == R.id.devsite) {
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.izhandroidapps.blogspot.in");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Loading, Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.call) {
            Intent i =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+919948918505"));
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.whatsapp) {

            //startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", //Uri.parse());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=919948918505&text=Hello"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(intent);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent localIntent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            localIntent2.setType("text/plain");
            localIntent2.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "Spread word");
            localIntent2.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "null");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent2, "Share via"));


        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (wv.canGoBack()) {

                        wv.goBack();

                    } else {
                        finish();

                    }

                    return true;


            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I think it is due to runtime permission
log on crashing

> Blockquote
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
>       at com.izhandroid.izhandroidapps.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:345)
>       at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2694)
>       at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3115)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
>       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:323)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4390)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4361)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3905)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3958)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3924)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4051)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3932)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4108)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3905)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3958)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3924)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3932)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3905)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3958)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3924)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4084)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4252)
>       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2437)
>       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2001)
>       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1992)
>       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2414)
>       at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

here are the screenshots

[On installing and launching running successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FMSU.png)

[does not respond and crashes on launching second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK5Hf.png)

Comment: Having so many imports in your sample code suggests that you are trying to do too many things at once in your class. It is a good idea to separate responsibility into separate classes, which will help you to debug your programs.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts No no it was causing due to runtime permission. Problem was solved after removing it. Can please go through my code and see whats wrong?